# Office js api- compressed buffer, type not able to open the documents back

Tags: openxml, docx, office-js

referred following code to achieve our use case:
http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync
We used above reference code to fetch to currently opened document from word/ppt into Office Open XML ("Office.FileType.Compressed") format slices. We combined those slices into string. We tried two ways to regenerate the document.
1.       We downloaded the same document to local file system (our JS download method attached in download.txt).
2.       We passed it as payload to our POST REST service method.
We used MIME type as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document for docx or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation for pptx.
We are not able open/regenerate the original docx or pptx document once we store it by combining compressed form slices. MS word/ppt always asks to repair the document. Repair does not retrieve the document.
Could you let us know how we can overcome this problem with office JS? Could you provide sample code to regenerate document from compressed slices?
Please clarify if the steps mentioned in the articles applies for Microsoft Exchange server.

Comment: It may be useful to format your question better. It is confusing and difficult to read. You will increase your chance of someone answering. I would have tried to edit it but looks like I may change what you need. Check out this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word.md and see if it helps on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there a way that we can fetch the document back inside the excel and powerpoint app? there is no api i can find to do that ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with proper encoding decoding. Base64 encoding decoding solves the problem

Comment: Can please elaborate on how did you fix this?